# check multiple MYSQL rows of data from a value and email the result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in MYSQL called Registration, Every Month a car check must be done. the user once the car check has been done will upload all the values online.

My Goal is to check if all Car Registrations have been done for the Month and if they Haven't send an Email to let them know that, that vehicle hasnt been checked, i am using cron job to run the code but that isnt the issue.

My problem is that when i go to check if all vehicle Registrations have been done. The emails that are responsible for checking  check each row at a time. meaning even if all have been done a bunch of email will appear saying it has been done because not every registration was inputted into that singular row

I want the code to check the entire column and see if there are any registrations missing so that the emails will only send once for the column instead of once per row here is how my code is structured.

```php
<?php

session_start();

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Username", "Password", "Database");

        require("PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
        require("PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");
    
    
        $query = "SELECT Registration FROM vehiclecheck WHERE ID_carcheck";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   

    
if($query_run) {

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

    if($row["Registration"] != "267AD7")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 267AD7 has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "244XST")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 244XST has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "572ZKK")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 572ZKK has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "072TVX")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 072TVX has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "348ZVB")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 348ZVB has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "066XXM")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 066XXM has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }
    if($row["Registration"] != "063ZCD")
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
    $mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
    $mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
    $mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
    $mail->Body = "A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, 063ZCD has not been Completed";
    $mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");
    $mail->send();
    }


     }
}
```

Comment: Hello, you shouldn't share your e-mail's username and password here

Comment: At first, if you have some parts of code that just repeat each other, you should make a function of it and call it when it needed. Second, now your code will send tons of emails because each row won't match for at least six conditions.

Comment: Firstly, the username and password aren't the actual username and password there just there as place holder, i should've just left it blank. Secondly how would I make a function that can call the email instead of just repeating the output with different values. and thirdly that is the problem i was trying to describe, is there a way to call the column so that when it does a check it will check all rows in the email at once instead of one row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making this possible in PHP code, you should be thinking about changing the SQL query

```
SELECT Registration FROM vehiclecheck 
WHERE Registration NOT IN ('267AD7', '244XST',
 '572ZKK', '072TVX', '348ZVB', '066XXM', '063ZCD')
```

Or you can create a table which holds all the code and meaning of each code something like table named `RegistrationCode`. Then write SQl as below

```
SELECT Registration FROM vehiclecheck 
WHERE Registration NOT IN 
(SELECT Code from RegistrationCode 
WHERE status = 'INVALID')
```

If more than one Registration entry of the same person is made then make the SQL query to check the date and last status of the registration done

```
SELECT Registration FROM vehiclecheck 
WHERE Registration R NOT IN 
(SELECT Code from RegistrationCode 
WHERE status = 'INVALID') 
AND RegistrationDate = 
(SELECT MAX(RegistrationDate ) from Registration S
WHERE S.CustomerId = R.CustomerId)
```

Then don't need a if condition at all to send email

Second MySQL table `RegistrationCode`

| Code | status |
| --- | --- |
| 267AD7 | INVALID |
| 244XST | INVALID |
| 572ZKK | INVALID |
| 072TVX | INVALID |
| 348ZVB | INVALID |
| 066XXM | INVALID |
| 063ZCD | INVALID |

Left Join Example

```
SELECT V.Registration FROM vehiclecheck V 
LEFT JOIN RegistrationCode C ON V.Registration = C.Code 
WHERE C.status = 'INVALID' 
AND RegistrationDate = 
(SELECT MAX(RegistrationDate ) from Registration S
 WHERE S.CustomerId = V.CustomerId)
```

You can change your PHP code like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "atqldhub.com.au";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "info@atqldhub.com.au";
$mail->Password = "5%226}Mh@Cdb";
$mail->SetFrom("info@atqldhub.com.au");
$mail->Subject = "Vehicle Checklist";
$mail->AddAddress("alex.crabtree@atqld.com.au");

$body = "";

if($query_run) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        $body = $body."<br/>A Vehicle has not been completed for this Month Registration, ".$row["Registration"]." has not been Completed";
    }
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->send();
}
```

Now you have a single email send only once with accumulated body content inside the while loop

Comment: That first option option you provide looks like the type of solution i am after.I am not sure how i would structure out the email without an if statement to determine the  name of the Registration as if that value wasnt there, their would be no way to tell the user that registration without writing out its name meaning you would need an if statement for every value you wanted to email. im not clear on what the SQL in that first statement does but if there was any way you could show me an example of how you would handle this so that i can have a clearer understanding of how this SQL code works

Comment: I would also like to thank your for your assistance in helping me so far it is appreciated

Comment: that is why I gave second and third solution so that you can substitute this body message `244XST has not been Completed` with a string contact from the second table using SQL JOINS

Comment: I think i might understand where i am confused. i would like to check something when you spoke about changing the SQL query did you mean to do it with the php or inside of phpmyadmin where SQL is. i am sorry if i am frustrating you i have only been coding for about a year and am still trying to get used to everything.

Comment: `$query = "<put the entire SQL here>"`

Comment: I would like to know how to properly structure out my emails next i dont really understand clearly what to write or where to put the email after the query is written.